# ServiceApiController Method not found when using HttpPost and ComplexType (Sitecore 8.1.3)

Tags: webapi, routing

I am working on refactoring some code and want to create WebApi services to do so.  I have created an initialization pipeline that registers custom routes.  I am still able to follow base sitecore ssc webapi methods if need be.

My issue is that I am not able to get my Post controller method to bind to my ajax post request JSON object. High level I have a controller method called Post, the method parameter is an object with two public properties, `FirstName` and `LastName`. In my ajax request I set the `contentType` to `application/json` and set the following as data:

```
{"FirstName":"first", "LastName": "last"}
```

The pieces are as follows:

1. Controller

   ```
   public class MyApiController : ServicesApiController
   ```
2. Controller Method

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult Search([FromBody]SearchRequest searchRequest)
   ```
3. Model Class

   ```
   [Serializable]    
   public class SearchRequest
   {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. CustomRoute

   ```
   DefaultRouteMapper.MapRoutes(config);

   var routes = config.Routes;

   routes.MapHttpRoute("Test_Search",
       "sitecore/api/test/{controller}",
        new { controller = "MyApi" });
   ```
5. Ajax Method

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'Post',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: { "FirstName" : "first", "LastName" : "last" },
      url: '/sitecore/api/test/myapi'
   });
   ```

I appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: I can see one error in your code: you use for json : firstName and in complex type you have FirstName; Can you check ?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? Have you confirmed that the ajax request is definitely going out as a post? It looks like there is a comma missing after the object being passed to data.

Comment: @Teeknow, sorry for the typo.  In the Javascript there is a comma after data.  Using JQuery 1.11.0.  Yes I am sure the request in made as a post.  I can see in Chrome development tools, the request is made with a post.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber, after changing the properties in the JSON to match the case in my Model class, I still get the 404.

Comment: @DerekPort no problem. Can you try removing your route and making the request to the default contorller route which should be the following: `/sitecore/api/myapi/{put_your_method_here}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.  There was another controller with the same name.  Once I changed the name of the controller to something unique, I got the expected results.

I'm a bit surprised that I didn't get a different exception, but nonetheless I'm moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use the `JSON.stringify()` to pass an object.

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'Post',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify({ "firstName" : "first", "lastName" : "last" })
   url: '/sitecore/api/test/myapi'
});
```

Comment: No change after changing data parameter to use JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before if u set default controller or method Sitecore has thrown 404 for me too.

Try setting the custom route as below:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute1", "sitecore/api/test/{controller}/{action}");
```

More info on creating a custom route here - [creating custom routes in sitecore](http://sitecoreblog.tools4geeks.com/Blog/38/Creating-a-web-API-in-sitecore-for-ajax-calls-with-in-sitecore-context)

Comment: No luck using the approach above.

Comment: Are you overriding any sitecore 404 code?